# Kohana Database Query Builder custom sort order ("ORDER BY Field (id, 1, 3, 2)" in MySQL)

Tags: sql-order-by, kohana, builder

I have a set of id's to select, so I request:

```
$ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
$q = DB::select('field1', 'field2', 'field3')->
     from('work')->
     where('field1', 'in', $ids)->execute();
```

How can I sort them in my custom order, like MySQL's 'ORDER BY Field' do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [DB::Expr](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/query/builder#database-expressions)

You can use it like so:

```
->order_by(DB::Expr('FIELD(`field`, 3,1,2)'))
```

Note, you'll have to manually escape the contents

Comment: Good answer, but actually you can just use `->order_by('FIELD("id", 1, 2, 3)')`, no need for DB::expr. Still need to escape the field values properly though, which could be done with `->order_by('FIELD("id", :f1, :f2)')->param(':f1', $f1)->param(':f2', $f2)`.

Comment: Indeed, I (kind of) forgot about that; that's what you get for working on non-kohana projects for too long..

Comment: you definitely need DB::expr, if you use table prefixes.